# Python не импортирует модули, Windows8

Tags: python

Начинаю изучать Python 3.4. Есть модули с расширением py, сохраненные в папке. В свойствах они соотносятся с Python Launcher for Windows (Console) Команда import их не открывает/запускает. Ошибка для всех одинакова:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>  
    import script1   
ImportError: No module named 'script1'
```

При этом кликом мыши они открываются, если выполнить Run Module, выполняются.

Как сделать, чтоб можно было их импортировать?

**Обновление**

Ответ: У меня в той же директории была поставлена версия Питона 2.7.10. После её удаления импорт заработал. Всё, что пробовал до этого, описано ниже.

Comment: ну, во-первых, надо привести код, которым вы их импортируете, а во-вторых, надо привести структуру файлов, чтобы знать где они расположены

Comment: Код import script1 .Создаю файлы в той же директории, куда поставил Python 34, в отдельной папке. Содержание файла, примерно, print (8**100).

Comment: Полная структура расположения файлов? `print(sys.path)`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    print (sys.path)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: В переменной path в Свойствах системы дописывал следующее: C:\Python34

Comment: Ну можно было и додуматься сделать `import sys` перед принтом.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, буду исправляться. Спасибо за наставления, ибо я совсем "деревянный" и пока что следую первым страницам книги... ['', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Итак, решил проверить все возможные варианты решения.

Comment: sys.path показывает C:\\Python34. В то же время в переменную  path я дописал   C:\Python34. Думал, добавлю \ в path и всё заработает, но нет. И в path остальные адреса написаны с одним \. Короче, не там я ищу, но где?,, Всем предыдущим участникам спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Всё заработало. Подозреваю, что такая ошибка была вызвана наличием папки с версией 2.7.10. Убрал её, удалил папку, всё импортируется. Всем "ИЗВИНИТЕ ЗА БЕСПОКОЙСТВО И СПАСИБО!"